# Select inner JOIN with multiple ids

Tags: mysql, inner-join

How can i read about 80 diffrent Fields from another Table with their values?
without making the query too long

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

I need to combine them.
There are about 80 fields.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON ???
```

Comment: Welcome to the joys of EAV models. You will need to join table_1 to table_2 once for each field. With 80 fields, you might find it easier to do this in your application layer.

Comment: Note that if all entries in table_1 have all the same fields (as it appears from your sample) you may as well just store the values directly into table_1 rather than using another table (table_2) for them. It will cost some space for duplicated fields but your queries will be a *lot* faster and storage is generally cheaper than time...

Comment: tnx, i think i will do that

Comment: Within sql, there are two standard ways, one of which is discussed in adjacent correspondence. But consider instead handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear you have to do something like this

```
SELECT t1.id
  ,t1.main_id,
  ,t1.web_ids
  ,t2.value as herstellerinterne_baureihebezeichnung
  ,t3.value as modell_start 
  ... 
FROM table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.herstellerinterne_baureihebezeichnung
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t3 ON t3.id = t1.modell_start

usw.
```

for all 80 columns.
Or you could build a stored procedure, where you would build a select statement by itself (loop through all columns (without the first 3) and execute it, but for that you must post your tables as text.